# Angular2 Final does not work under IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

It worked for some time and after that stopped. Probably, I imported some component or did something. It works on Firefox, Chrome, Edge, but not on IE11.

The error I get is from the Angular2 core library.

It says

**SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference**

and points to this function

```
            function combine(options) {
                return (_a = ((Object))).assign.apply(_a, [{}].concat(options));
                var _a;
            }
```

from angular intl.ts file
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/intl.ts

How I can fix this and make it work on IE?

Comment: did you load the polyfills?

Comment: how to check that I loaded polyfills? I have this file polyfills.ts structure, but not sure if it is included.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html

Comment: thanks, I verified and polyfills is included by webpack in polyffils.bundle.js but it still doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 IE11 Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276692/angular2-ie11-unable-to-get-property-apply-of-undefined-or-null-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Babel script in index.html may help you:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser-polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

While using angular2 CLI 2.4.* the above issue will occur in IE.

To resolve this issue make sure that you have imported the items which is need for polyfills in polyfills.ts file using angular CLI

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/

    import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
    import 'core-js/es6/object';
    import 'core-js/es6/function';
    import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
    import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
    import 'core-js/es6/number';
    import 'core-js/es6/math';
    import 'core-js/es6/string';
    import 'core-js/es6/date';
    import 'core-js/es6/array';
    import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
    import 'core-js/es6/map';
    import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Its working for me.