# Angular CLI title did not show 'app works!'

Tags: angular

I installed Angular CLI 1.0.1 successfully.

After I run ng server and go http://localhost:4200 using IE 11, it always showing "loading..." instead of "app works!"

```
ng-v
@angular/cli: 1.0.1
node: 6.10.2
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 4.1.0
@angular/compiler: 4.1.0
@angular/core: 4.1.0
@angular/forms: 4.1.0
@angular/http: 4.0.3
@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.0
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.0
@angular/router: 4.1.0
@angular/cli: 1.0.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.0
```

Anyone know what am I missing from the install or config?
the angular cli installed successfully.
I follow the

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new myproject
cd myproject
ng serve
```

Open http://localhost:4200 and always show "Loading... "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is knowing Angular 2 not working in IE 9 - 11 issue, please see https://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/angular-not-working-in-ie11 and [Angular2 IE11 Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276692/angular2-ie11-unable-to-get-property-apply-of-undefined-or-null-reference)
After I install:

```
npm i mdn-polyfills --save
```

and modify the file under the project src\polyfills.ts, add following code

```
import "core-js/client/shim"; // or load it before other angular2 & zone.js stuff
import "zone.js";
import "reflect-metadata";
```

Wow, it is works!!!

Answer (score 1):

You must have javascrip errors. Make sure you open your browser javascript console and look for errors. This might be related to partialy installed npm packages. Try installing by running : npm install from a console in your project folder.
For your setting, please edit your package.json file and use @angular/http version 4.1.0 and npm install again

Comment: You are right, here is the error I got 
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference
vendor.bundle.js (27377,5), what I need to do? reinstall npm?

Comment: Try to npm install again.

Comment: after reinstall npm, same problem

Comment: You do not need to re install npm or node. Go to folder where your project is and run command on a console : npm install

Comment: Same thing, I got warn when install: optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0, npm warning notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform from fsevents@1.1.1:; npm warn @angular/http@4.0.3 requires a peer of @anguar/core@4.03 but none was installed; npm warn @angular/http@4.03 requires a peer of @angular/platform-brower@4.0.3 but none was installed.

Comment: Sorry, where the node file locate? my project is on d:/myproject

Comment: Edit your d:\myproject\package.json file and run npm install again

Comment: "@angular/http": "4.1.0" or "@angular/http": "^4.1.0" both did not work after install npm