# How fix "Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference" error with asp.net core, angular 4

Tags: asp.net, angular

I am using the aspnetcore-spa template, creating a project with the command "dotnet new angular". See https://jonhilton.net/2017/02/21/create-a-vs2017-angular-2-and-net-core-site-using-the-command-line/. The current set of templates is version 1.0.3, which adds Angular 4.1.2 to the npm dependencies. This works great to get a project running quickly.

However, right out of the box, the "counter" page does not work with IE 11. If you navigate to the "counter" link, and look at IE's console, you will see the message: "Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference". And when you click the "Increment" button, nothing happens. (It works fine for Chrome and Firefox, but not IE.)

I did some digging, and it seems that the root of the problem is that the .assign method is not implemented in IE11. See [Angular2 IE11 Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276692/angular2-ie11-unable-to-get-property-apply-of-undefined-or-null-reference)

The fix, according to the link above, is to import the Object.assign polyfill by MDN. However, I don't know how to accomplish that in the project. What I have tried is:

1) Add to package.json: "mdn-polyfills": "^3.5.0"

2) Add ''mdn-polyfills' to webpack.config.vendors.js

3) Run "webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js" from a command prompt at the root of the project folder, which results in an error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mdn-polyfills'
```

I don't know what to do next. Steps 1 and 2 above do not resolve the problem. I tried adding to app.module.shared.ts the following:

```
import 'mdn-polyfills/Object.assign';
```

This compiled fine, but did not help anything. I am not planning to use the counter page anyway, of course, but I get the same error (in IE 11 only) on a form I have created in a component I actually do care about.

So, once again, I am left to struggle with how to set up an environment that works, rather than actually coding Angular components. Oh, how I miss the days when I could just add a package via NuGet and it would just work!

If anyone can help, it would be most appreciated.

**UPDATE**: After finding this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-object-assign, I added  "es6-object-assign":  "1.1.0"  to package.json, then added 'es6-object-assign' to webpack.config.vendors.js, then ran webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js" from a command prompt (no errors). I then added the following at the top of my app.component.ts file:

```
import 'es6-shim';
import 'es6-promise';
import 'event-source-polyfill';
import 'es6-object-assign';
```

None of it made any difference. I still get "Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference" error. I also note that this error appears on every single page, though it only seems to impact functionality of the counter page (Increment button does nothing).

I have verified that the source of the problem is indeed the .assign method. The error is coming from the vendor.js file, at the return line below:

```
function combine(options) {
    return ((Object)).assign.apply(((Object)), [{}].concat(options));
}
```

There must be a way to fix this, but I am at a loss...

**NEW UPDATE**: I am confident that this is not the right way to address this issue, but in desperation I just added a script at the top of my _Layout.cshtml page, which I found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

This does fix the issue, and makes the counter page work correctly, but it is clearly not the "Angular way", so I am not considering this solution to be an answer to my question. If anyone can show me the right way to solve this problem, I would consider that the answer.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this issue that you like? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 5):

In order to solve the problems with `vendor.js` in function

```html
function combine(options) {
    return ((Object)).assign.apply(((Object)), [{}].concat(options));
}
```

One solution is to work with `polyfills.ts` as says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46764770/polyfills-ts-in-my-angular-2-asp-net-core-application-created-using-vs-template?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But in many cases do not have `polyfills.ts` file... So in this cases the solution that works for me is this....

Under `ClientApp` directory of the solution there is a file called

```
boot.browser.ts
```

Under line 2 that that says

```
import 'zone.js';
```

Add this

```html
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/***********added*************/
```

And this should work.

Comment: Works for me! Thanks!

Comment: I only have a boot.client.ts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this :
in CMD line   go to your  aspnetcore-spa template project folder

C:\Users\Jo\angularDemos2>`dotnet restore`

To pull down all the Nuget packages

then type

C:\Users\Joffr\angularDemos2>`npm install`

To pull down all the dependencies from the JASON file

Answer (score 0):

Actually First  make sure your using EDGE  and not IE  this should solve you concat issues in the Vendor.js file.

for more info use Mr May Tutorial

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2017-Launch/WEB-103

Comment: You can't always decide what browser someone "has to use". If you are working with a customer that uses and older browser, you something just have to make it work.