# Polyfills.ts in my Angular 2 ASP.NET Core application created using VS template, are they missing?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I'm newbie in Angular development and I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Professional template to start creating an Angular 2 application with ASP.Net Core:
[image]

My problem is that the app doesn't run on Internet Explorer 11 and searching I have found that I have to uncomment something on `polyfills` file.

I have found it on `D:\MyProjects\NetCore\AngularWebApplication\AngularWebApplication\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js` but it doesn't have the same content that expected (like the ones show in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44631123/68571)).

Is it a good idea to use VS template or maybe I can use the Empty template and add the Angular app to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came across this same problem - and fortunately the fix is dead simple.

Put your `polyfills.ts` file in the same directory as the `boot.browser.ts` file (I ran an `ng new test-app` command in a temp directory just to get the latest files), than add the following line at the top of the `boot.browser.ts` file:-

`import './polyfills';`

You'll then have to remove the commented out bits in `polyfills.ts` file to include the required imports for the browsers you want to support, and also run and `npm install` commands that are required (as specified in the comments on the lines in `polyfills.ts`).

That should fix the IE11 problem for you.

You mentioned using an Empty template then creating an app using `ng new`, but it's not a trivial task getting it (and debugging) working in Visual Studio, so you're probably better off using VS Code if you're going down that route. If you can deploy to an environment that supports `.net core` and `node.js`, then you're probably better off using the .net core Angular template.

Comment: There is a package in `packages.json` called `mdn-polyfills` and I'm not sure if this is the one I need to use.

Comment: I didn't use a package - I just used the latest `polyfills.ts` file from angular.io (you can get it by creating a new angular app by running `ng new testapp` or just download it from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/public/docs/_examples/cli-quickstart/ts/src/polyfills.ts)

Answer (score 5):

if you do not have `polyfills.ts` file read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641907/how-fix-unable-to-get-property-apply-of-undefined-or-null-reference-error-wi/49210713#49210713)

You have to open `ClientApp-->boot.browser.ts` file.

Under line 2

> import 'zone.js';

Add this

```html
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/***********added*************/
```

And this should work

Comment: Thanks! This helped me fix a vs2019 angular project with typescript which was due for a fix for a long time.