# What's a good alternative to Object.assign?

Tags: javascript

I have

```
var shared = {
}

var stuff = Object.assign(Object.create(shared),{
   //stuff
});
```

But Object.assign doesn't work on Safari and I don't wanna use something like Babel since my website is already kinda laggy. Is there any good alternative to make it so I can do this while maintaining "stuff" inheritance to "shared"..

```
var shared = {
}

var stuff = Object.create(shared);
stuff = {//stuff
};
```

I realize I can simply assign properties one by one to "stuff" but I have a lot of properties there and it would make the code a lot less organized

Comment: Why not polyfill `Object.assign`?

Comment: How would the number of properties that are assigned to a separate object make the code "less organized"?

Comment: Babel Laggy? News to me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: `stuff = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(shared))` ?

Comment: check out [polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Object.assign not appear to work on Safari 8.0.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916592/why-does-object-assign-not-appear-to-work-on-safari-8-0-7)

Comment: @Thomas awesome, polyfill.io definitely worked. Do you think it's bad for performance though?

Answer (score 0):

If you want another way to copy properties, how about something like this (copies everything from A to B):

```
const a = {hello:1, world:2};
const b = {};
Object.keys(a).forEach(k => b[k] = a[k]);
// b is now {hello:1, world:2}.
```

Comment: this will not `clone` objects but it will hold references only

Comment: Well, neither does `Object.assign()`. If you want to deep clone an object that's a different problem.

Comment: You are right, it will not. I though it would by default, at least for first level entries

Comment: But since I'm also using Object.create() isn't what I'm doing less of a copy and more of just adding the first object to the second object prototype chain? Or is that basically the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want quick dirty solution with minimal change to your codebase, try this pkg https://github.com/rubennorte/es6-object-assign

In my opinion, you should use bundling framework, say webpack, alongside with babel. There are many ways to reduce the bundled file size like tree-shaking, minifying, separating vendor files and sending JS files gzipped to the browser and it is not laggy at all.